# Elastic Search - Difference betweeen timestamp of 2 child documents

Tags: elasticsearch, parent-child

I have a parent-child relationship betweeen documents as described in the official documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/parent-child.html).

The child documents has a field "timestamp". I need to compute/query the difference between 2 different child's timestamp.

Example:

```
                         parent document
                          |          |
                          |          |
              child document 1     child document 2
              * timestamp1         * timestamp2
```

The value I want is: timestamp2 - timestamp1

Changing the child documents to nested objects in the parent is not an option.

For what a read, using scripts is not possible as child's field cannot be accessed from the parent document.

I'm using the Java API.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you do this computation at index time and store the differences explicitly?

Comment: The thing is I have a lot of child documents per parent, I'm loking for a more flexible solution than calculating and storing the differences explicity.

Comment: Can you use scripting, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html

Comment: Scripting was the only possible way to do it, not a perfect solution anyway...